# how i can create custom progress indicators in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How can I make a custom circular progress indicator like the ones in the below image in Flutter?

[Gif of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFMhw.gif)

Comment: This is called a shimmer effect. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with the [`Shimmer`](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer) package.
Add the Shimmer package to your project and use it like this.

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 100.0,
  child: Shimmer.fromColors(
    baseColor: Colors.red,
    highlightColor: Colors.yellow,
    child: Text(
      'Shimmer',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40.0,
        fontWeight:
        FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```